# Haskell function to duplicate

Tags: haskell

If a lizard's tail gets cut off, say two more get regrown. If I have the data type below, how would I write a function to be able to duplicate how many tails are grown?

```
data Lizard = Tail
    deriving (Eq, Show)

duplicate :: Lizard -> Lizard
duplicate Tail?? = ???
```

so the input

```
> duplicate Tail
```

should give

```
> Tail Tail
```

Answer (score 7):

Your desired result `Tail Tail` is not a Lizard anymore. Actually `Tail Tail` is not a valid value at all. Also your function `duplicate` cannot do much as it takes a Lizard and returns a Lizard and the only possible Lizard is `Tail`.

If you want Lizards with multiple Tails you need to reflect this in your Lizard datatype, e.g. as

```
data Tail = Tail deriving (Eq, Show)
data Lizard = Lizard [Tail] deriving (Eq, Show)

duplicate :: Lizard -> Lizard
duplicate (Lizard ts) = Lizard (ts++ts)

result = duplicate (Lizard [Tail])
```

This gives you

```
*Main> result
Lizard [Tail,Tail]
```

or applied twice

```
*Main> duplicate result
Lizard [Tail,Tail,Tail,Tail]
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you use `Tail Tail` is not going to work for a datatype `data Lizard = Tail`, because `Tail` as you define it is a constructor that takes no arguments.

**Mutant duplicators**

If you want to use a constructor for each tail you can do something like the following:

```
data Lizard = Mutant Lizard Lizard | Tail

duplicate :: Lizard -> Lizard
duplicate l = Mutant l l
```

Then `duplicate Tail` will give `Mutant Tail Tail`. Duplicating that will give `Mutant (Mutant Tail Tail) (Mutant Tail Tail)`.

**Lists of tails**

If it doesn't have to be all encoded in data but using values is also OK you can do this:

```
data Tail = Tail
data Lizard = LizMonster [Tail] | Lizard Tail

duplicate :: Lizard -> Lizard
duplicate (Lizard t) = LizMonster [t,t]
duplicate (LizMonster ts) = LizMonster (ts ++ ts)
```

You could also say that a `Lizard` with 1 tail is not so different from a monster with many tails and use `Lizard [Tail]` for all your cases. (Then you will probably want to define something like `oneTail = Lizard [Tail]` because using a list for a single tail might be a bit unintuitive).

**From Tail to Bottom**

If you're not only interested in duplications we can define a lizard which is very similar to a list of tails. This will give you output a bit closer to what you're looking for:

```
data Lizard = Tail Lizard | Bottom deriving (Show)

noTail :: Lizard
noTail = Bottom

oneTail :: Lizard
oneTail = Tail Bottom

duplicate :: Lizard -> Lizard
duplicate (Tail t) = Tail . Tail $ duplicate t
duplicate Bottom = Bottom

-- Additional benefit: we can make siamese lizards
siamese :: Lizard -> Lizard -> Lizard
siamese (Tail t1) t = Tail $ siamese t1 t
siamese Bottom t = t
```

If we check how this shows up in for example GHCi it's quite close to what you want:

```
duplicate oneTail
-- gives Tail (Tail Bottom)
```

And we can do more fancy stuff:

```
siamese (oneTail) (duplicate oneTail)
-- gives Tail (Tail (Tail Bottom))
```

Arguably, if you keep on cutting off a lizard's tails, you might get something that more closely resembles the tree-like structure from the first suggestion though.

Comment: `Lizard`s with `Bottom` are just Peano nats. Hence you need to recurse only on the first argument in `siamese`.

Comment: The `siamese t Bottom = t` part is not needed.

Comment: @user3237465: I understand it's not needed, but the point of recursing only on the first argument is to save operations right? And this saves operations as well: if we add 0 to a number, we don't have to traverse all the way through the number before finally adding the 0, we can just return the number directly. Actually I think we could recurse on both, but as soon as *one of the two* is a bottom finish our recursion. If we add *m* and *n*, the current operation takes ~ *m* time, by recursing on both I think it would take ~ *2 min(m, n)* which could be better in some cases.

Comment: My point was about simplicity rather than efficiency. I now think that your original definition is more appropriate, sorry for the misleading comment.

Comment: No problem, you've convinced me to go for simplicity for the example's sake :)

Comment: If every lizard has at least one tail, you can use `data Lizard = Lizard Tail [Tail]`, which is the same idea as the definition of the `NonEmpty` type, `data NonEmpty a = NonEmpty a [a]`; so a lizard could be `newtype Lizard = Lizard (NonEmpty Tail)`. If the tails don't have any information, you can (with recent GHC), import `Numeric.Natural` and use `newtype Lizard = Lizard Natural`, interpreting the natural number as either the number of tails or the number of tails minus 1.